# Why am I teleporting not to the set coordinates, but 1 block off?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

For some reason, whenever I use the `/tp` command, I teleport 1 block over on the positive X axis. For example, if I did "/tp -181 58 101", I would end up at the coordinates -180 58 101. I don't know if it's a problem with my computer, or the save file, but if it's either of those, or anything else, can anyone tell me what's happening?

Answer (score 8):

This is actually completely normal. If you run the command `/tp -181 58 101`, you will not get teleported to those exact coordinates. If you look at the decimals, you will notice you got teleported to `-180.5 58 101.5`. That's because you get automatically teleported to the **middle** of a block, so the game finds the closest middle point of a block, which is why you are half a block off if you teleport to negative coordinates (it works on the Z axis too). It's simply because -181 rounds to -180.5 rather than -181.5.

If you need exact coordinates, type in your decimal places:

```
/tp -181.0 58 101.0
```

Like this, however, you will get teleported in between 4 blocks. If you want to get teleported to the middle of that block simply put .5 in the decimal place, like so:

```
/tp -181.5 58 101.5
```